# Request from desktop client hits the wrong controller action

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

From a Windows Forms desktop application, I make a request to an end-point in my ASP.NET MVC Web Application (not Web API).

The request is made for the endpoint "~/Account/APILogin" but it hits the "~/Account/Login" (GET) action even when I am making a post request to the former. Why is that so?

Here are the relevant bits of code:

**In the ASP.NET MVC Application**

```
class AccountController : Controller
{
    // The request comes to this guy
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        // get request for Web browser clients
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // post request for Web browser clients
    }


    // It should really have hit this
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult APILogin(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        if (loginRequest == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginRequest.UserName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginRequest.Password))
        {
            return Json(LoginResult.CreateFailure("Invalid login. Please try again."));
        }

        var hashedPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(loginRequest.Password);

        var user = BusinessManager.GetUser(loginRequest.UserName, hashedPassword);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return Json(LoginResult.CreateFailure("Invalid login. Please try again."));
        }

        return Json(LoginResult.CreateSuccess());
    }
}
```

**In the Global.asax of the ASP.NET MVC Web Application**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
    }
}
```

**In the Windows Forms desktop client application**

```
private async void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new Client();

    var loginRequest = new LoginRequest { UserName = txtUserName.Text.Trim(), Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim() };

    var loginResult = await client.LoginAsync(loginRequest);

    if (loginResult.Succeeded)
    {
        Close();
    }
    else
    {
        ReportInvalidLogin(loginResult.FailureMessage);
    }
}
```

**In a class library that makes the HTTP Request on behalf of clients to the ASP.NET Web Web Application**

```
class Client : IDisposable
{
private WebClient _webClient = null;
private string _baseUrl = null;

    public Client()
    {
        _webClient = new WebClient();
        _baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApplicationBasePath"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_baseUrl))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Please add a key named WebApplicationBasePath to the configuration file with the base Url of the server web application.");
        }
    }

    public async Task<LoginResult> LoginAsync(LoginRequest loginRequest)
    {
        var loginUrl = string.Format($"{_baseUrl}Account/APILogin");

        var data = await Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest));
        _webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
        var responseString = await _webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(loginUrl, "POST", data);
        var loginResult = await Task.Factory.StartNew<LoginResult>(() => 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(responseString));
        return loginResult;
    }
}
```

I do *not* have an `AuthorizeAttribute` applied yet, so that, too, as a possible cause is out of the question.

Comment: `APILogin` doesn't have `[AllowAnonymous]` therefore you must be logged in to access it. Presumably somewhere else you've configured authentication to be required (such as web.config or by applying a global filter)

Comment: @mason Thanks. I thought of that, too. But that isn't the case. I do not have any authentication applied to any route anywhere yet.

Comment: Just as an experiment, try applying the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @mason Sure, thank you. Trying that out now.

Comment: @mason Thank you. That was it. And it is strange. I did not configure authentication anywhere. I used the Katana infrastructure that comes out of the box with the MVC template if you configure individual accounts, but I invested a great amount of effort to make sure I customized it to my needs and moved things around. Thank you. Please put that down as an answer. I will examine more once I get the debug symbols for `System.Web.Mvc.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your stack (possibly IIS settings, web.config, or applying a global filter) authentication is being required for all requests, unless explicitly marked with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. The solution is simple, add that attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public JsonResult APILogin(LoginRequest loginRequest)
```